# In what cases should I use 条 for 猫?

Tags: grammar, measure-word

I learned that the measure word for 猫 is `只`.

However, my friend said 条 is the correct measure word for 猫.

The conversation with the friend is the following:

> X: 你有养猫吗？
>
> I: 哈哈 这只不是我的，我韩国旅游时的我的房东的。
>
> X: 我家有一条
>
> I: 猫应该是只还是条？
>
> X: 条

So she said clearly it should be 条, not 只.

But my Pleco only shows 只, while 网易有道词典 doesn't mention it.

Now I wonder in what cases 条 should be used instead of 只, and why 只 is not correct here.

Comment: I prefer to 只; 条 sounds weird. See [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/25403649?sort=created&page=1) and [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1959346010176276420.html).

Comment: users are used to 条 for dogs, although 条猫 does not seem to exist, on the other hand although 条狗 may be more common, examples for 只狗 abound, iciba (cf. comment #1):伴着一声嗥叫，第二只狗扑向了他的脚后跟,库克叫这只狗的名字时，它的耳朵就会稍稍耷拉一下,那只狗阴郁地盯着我们看了几分钟

Comment: 只 is right. I've never heard 一条猫, maybe it's her dialect.

Comment: @JasonSwift Then where 条 is used more often?

Comment: @user6065 Even on 狗, isn't 只 way more common...?

Comment: Both 一条狗 and 一只狗 are common. Here's a discussion on Zhihu: https://www.zhihu.com/question/31086186

Comment: see comment #1, 2nd "here": 如“一条狗”，也可叫“一只狗”，一般大个的狗用“条”，小个的狗

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Misusing quantifiers is a practice of rhetorics. Consider the examples of 一滩猫 and 一坨代码. 滩 gives a metaphor noting the liquidity of a cat, and 坨 implies that the code is badly programmed to look like shit.

In orthographic usages, 条 cannot quantify 猫. However, if you have a specific rhetorical purpose, you may quantify anything with any quantifier you prefer.

In this very particular case, when 条 is used to quantify 猫, it would seem that you are giving an explicit implication that the cat is pretty long or very thin; and note that context matters.

Answer (score 0):

In a mistake, I have never heard anyone say 一条猫. It does not make sense.

Because when people choose a counter, he have 3 options,

1st: a description.

一根鱼竿, 一条鱼,

2nd: a common counter.

一个铅笔, 一位好人,

3rd: an emotional counter

一条好汉, 一条狗, 一头疯子

一条狗 originally implies a hungry dog that is hollow and skinny, though it becomes a common counter, it still includes the negative meanings.

If you use 条 with other things, means you treat them as dogs, just like 一条好汉.

If 一条瘦猫, that is much better, a hateful hungry cat.